# Passing Variables when Sending Email from Access with VBA

Tags: html, vba

I have a simple HTML email routine on my Access form. It reads the HTML from a text file (there will be many text files when I have finished and they need to be edited each year).
Once read it sends the Email, This all works fine.

I need to be able to insert variables into the HTML, like Dear XXX and some balance amounts.
Can this be done with the set up I have?

This is the Text file

```
<p style="text-align: right;"><img src="https://www.abacusaccountants.co.uk/logo2.png" alt="" /></p>
<p>Dear </p> <var>name</var>
<p>You will shortly be receiving (if you haven't already received it) notification to complete your annual self-assessment Tax Return from HM Revenue and Customs.</p>
<p>Please note that the deadline for the submission of paper tax returns this year is the 31st October 2022 and in order to ensure that we can complete and submit your return on time we must have the return and all associated information and business records by the 31st August 2022 at the very latest.</p>
<p>We will, where possible, submit your tax return electronically and forward a paper copy to yourself for both your records and your approval. We will do this as soon as we believe we have all the required information to do so.</p>
<p>Should you have any queries then please do not hesitate to contact us.</p>
<p>We look forward to hearing from you.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Yours sincerely,</p>
```

And this is the VBA

```
Private Sub Command2209_Click()
Dim name As String
name = "Mr Bloggs"

'Read file
Dim iTxtFile As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFileText As String
strFile = "C:\Projects\5thApr.txt"
iTxtFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As FreeFile
strFileText = Input(LOF(iTxtFile), iTxtFile)
Close iTxtFile


Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myOutlApp As Outlook.Application

Set myOutlApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = myOutlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With myMail
    .To = "mobile@testemail.co.uk"
    .subject = "testing email from access"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = strFileText
    .Send
End With

Set myMail = Nothing
Set myOutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```